# How long ago, and how far away, could "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away" have been?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

Assume an event happened "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away", and assume this event includes intelligent carbon-based life forms. What are bounds$^{a}$ on the time and distance (from us) of this event?

$[a]$ Bounds that take into account the history of our universe. I think the sentence infers that the event happened inside our past light cone.

Comment: Are you hypothesizing that the Star Wars story is real and, asking about how we came to know of it here on Earth?  We probably didn't observe their light saber duels through any of our own Earth-made telescopes, so somebody from their galaxy must have brought the story here.  In that case, the answer to your question depends on the capabilities of their hyper-drive.

Comment: [vaguely related Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Star-Wars-creative-franchise/What-did-Lucas-have-in-mind-with-a-long-time-ago-in-a-galaxy-far-far-away)

Comment: This appears to be asking 'what is the furthest signal we've detected' which would be easily found with a simple internet search.

Comment: @KyleKanos That's a misreading of the question, which specifically requires the event to include carbon-based life-forms, i.e. the stage of development of the universe at which this became possible.

Comment: @Emilio: adding a few hundred thousand to million years on a several billion years is fairly insignificant, so it's not really misreading this at all.

Comment: @Kyle Maybe it's obvious to an astrophysicist that there was enough carbon around to support life by a few 100ky after the Big Bang, but it's not obvious at all to a layman; after all, it took a good ~9Gy for life as we know it to kick off. If you have good references for that figure, that would make a fantastic answer.

Comment: @Emilio: again, I try not answering crap questions.

Comment: I mean, seriously: Google 'furthest object observed' and then add whatever number you think might be reasonable for "life" (however it is defined by you) and you get an answer. Zero effort by op, outside of picking a click-bait title, IMO.

Comment: I also mean it seriously. Carbon-based life needs carbon, which rules out the epoch with only Population III stars present. From the get-go that's nontrivial astrophysics. I'm not saying it's a great question (and there's a big fuzziness which makes it not awesome, for sure), but there's nontrivial physics. If you don't like the question, just move on, but don't bash it without trying to understand it. For sure, the answer has nothing to do with the furthest object we've observed (with current tech? with 1977 tech?).

Comment: (On the other hand, I know the chances of you agreeing with me on anything are close to nil, so peace out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a partial answer, but:

- **How long ago?**  A prerequisite for intelligent carbon-based life forms to exist is that there are substantial amounts of carbon in the Universe.  This would probably limit us to some time after the Population III (ultra-low metallicity) stars burned out and the Population II (low-metallicity) stars took over.  It used to be thought that even the Population II stars didn't have enough "metals" for planets to form.  But [the Kepler probe's results](http://www.space.com/17441-universe-heavy-metals-planet-formation.html) seem to imply that this is not the case;  there have been plenty of planets found around low-metallicity stars, it's just that they're not usually gas giants and so we hadn't detected them before Kepler was launched.

  This gets us into the question of whether you need to have a gas giant in a stellar system in order for life to evolve.  It's been hypothesized that the influence of the gas giants in our solar system swept up a lot of comets and asteroids that would have otherwise impacted Earth and made things difficult for any proto-life.  So if you believe this, then you need a galaxy full of Population I stars rather than Population II stars, and the time window in which carbon-base life can exist opened that much later in the Universe.

  Finding information on how long ago the first Population III stars formed, built up carbon & oxygen, and blew said carbon & oxygen into the interstellar medium is remarkably difficult.  I'm not an expert in the subject, but I suspect that it's not really known.  (With [one recently found exception](http://www.eso.org/public/news/eso1524/), astronomers do not claim to have ever observed a Population III star.)  These stars would have formed during the reionization epoch, which happened a few hundred million years after the big bang, give or take a factor of three.  Certainly by the time we get to 1 billion years after the Big Bang, we have a good number of Population II stars around, and we can't rule out carbon-based life after that point.
- **How far away?**  Given the answer to the above question, an age of the Universe of about 14 billion years, and the question's requirement that the events have occurred in our light-cone, then we're probably looking at somewhere within 13 billion light-years of us.

Comment: The Pop III stuff is good, though a biologist might quibble that it took a few billion years for complex life to evolve once Earth formed. In any event, just to be pedantic, distances are somewhat tricky in cosmology. A galaxy at redshift 6 will appear to us as it looked 1 billion years after the Big Bang. When that light was emitted it would only have been 4 billion light years away. Its present position can be extrapolated to be 28 billion light years away, which is outside our event horizon (present-day light from that galaxy will never reach us).